# Extract fitted output from the trained model in Python (KERAS/TensorFlow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using KERAS with TensorFlow back-end. Suppose that this is the model block:

```
model.add(LSTM(units = 60, activation = 'tanh')
model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.5))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 200, batch_size = 32)
```

Is there any way to extract fitted output from the trained model (`model`)?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. You fit a model to the data, not the data to the model. If you want the data the model was trained on, you already have that: `X_train, Y_train`. Otherwise, please clarify your question

Comment: @G.Anderson I revised the question.

Comment: Unfortunately that edit didn't help much.  Are you trying to get the model's _predictions_ on the input data? Maybe it would help if you gave a sample of what you would like the "output" you're requesting to look like.

Comment: Do you mean feature vector from last fully connected layer?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably rephrase you question, as it is not clear what fitted output you try to achieve. I guess the most probable scenarios with respect to machine learning is that:

1. You have new input data `X`, and want to do a prediction with your fitted model. This can be done like this `model.predict(X)`.
2. Or you are trying to get the weights of the fitted model, which can be done like this `model.get_weights()`.